# Is it feasible to connect the WAN and LAN ports of a router to the same switch on an intranet?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, switch

My intranet structure is shown below:
[Old intranet structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swntV.png)

Previously, WIFI users were able to connect to my NAS, and I don't want that. And I also wanted to turn several separate WIFIs into one, so I planned an upgrade program. Like this:
[New intranet structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZd6i.png)

I'll configure the firewall on Router2 so that all addresses on subnetwork 11 can't access addresses on subnetwork 10. So my NAS will become secure. The question is: Is it feasible?What are the risks?

Thank you for your patience in reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, **not with an unmanaged switch**. If you want DHCP to continue working on both subnets, you'll have no control over which devices get what addresses – they all will get offers from *both* routers (DHCP servers) at the same time. At minimum, switches that support VLANs would be necessary for such "router on a stick" configuration (able to assign Wi-Fi AP ports to one VLAN, PC ports to another).

(If not VLANs, then you would need to set both DHCP servers to "known devices only" mode, which means you'd need to manually give IP addresses to every guest on Wi-Fi... or you would need to set one server to "delayed" mode, which a typical home-gateway router rarely supports.)

It is possible to deliberately run two separate subnets on the same shared Ethernet, but usually with a *single* DHCP server (to avoid unpredictable results) and with static DHCP leases assigning addresses either from one subnet or another. It is actually what I currently have at home for other (non-security) reasons, with the ISP's router having DHCP disabled and an additional router "on the side" providing DHCP for two subnets, very much like in your diagram.

However, addressing aside, such design **isn't particularly secure**; someone who knows their way around networks could very easily discover that going through router2 in such a setup is… entirely optional, because it is still a shared Ethernet after all – literally nothing stops them from manually assigning an IP address from the other subnet even if they're on Wi-Fi.

So if both networks must run over the same wiring, you *really* want to separate them for VLANs – both for DHCP to work right, and for any meaningful security.

---

(I'd also add that a router that has "WAN and LAN ports" is probably not going to be flexible enough for what you need, in general... like the labels say, those are only meant to sit between you and Internet, they're not meant for custom internal routing. It *would* work, with VLAN-capable switches handling the isolation, but it's not very tidy to have NAT all over the place.)

Comment: Very thorough and easy to understand answers, thank you very much!